# Is it "the right and left sides" or "the right and the left sides"?

Tags: definite-article

- Measure the height from the tool to the right and left sides of the metal plate.
- Measure the height from the tool to the right and the left sides of the metal plate.

I want people to mesure the tool height at two spots.

Which one is correct?

Also, if I want them to measure another two spots on the metal plate:

- measure the height from the tool to the front and back of the metal plate.

Is it proper to say "front and back"?

Answer (score 1):

Either form would be valid, but I would use "*...to the right and left sides ..." and I suspect that most fluent speakers would do so as well. Omitting repeated article,is very common, and quite valid. The same applies to "*to the front and back*"

By the way, while it depends on context, i suspect I would favor "*distance*" ovr "*height*" here.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll change height to distance.